# Moq + VB.NET - will it be fully supported in VS2010 automatically in its current form?

Tags: vb.net, unit-testing, tdd, mocking, moq

We are looking to make a final decision on our Mocking framework. After trying several, I have fallen in love with Moq. I also love TypeMock - but because we are in the early stages of implementing TDD across the team, we do not want to make such a large investment quite yet. We are using VS 2008 now and are going to move to 2010 as soon as it is released.

So after doing much research I have decided on Moq because it's nearly as good as TypeMock and has super clean syntax, etc. ***Now here's the problem/question: we are mainly a VB.NET shop but are using C# for all of our CRM implementation code (plugsins, etc). It seems Moq only fully supports  C# due to VB.NET lacking Lambda sub routines. Can anyone confirm that when VS2010 comes out Moq will work fully with VB.NET in its current version?***

Is anyone here using Moq with VB.NET? w/ 2010? We need to make this decision asap, as we are under tight deadline and do not want to change frameworks again (went from NMock to TypeMock and now want to make final decision and move to Moq) or have 2 seperate ones per language... any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Download the RC and try it in a VM. Seriously, just go do it!

(I reckon ther's a very strong chance it should work - I'm using Moq on 2008 and obviously have zero worries about it working with 2010. Moq is a very good choice IMNSHO)